# How to deploy Commerce Cloud code (SFRA version) using jenkins?

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, jenkins

We need to deploy SFRA code to development and staging instance.
Earlier for pipeline version, we had used Jenkins plugin i.e "OSF Builder Suite For Salesforce Commerce Cloud Deploy" to deploy to Commerce Cloud instances.

For SFRA version, as we need to use dw.json and do all the compilation of JS and CSS.

I am not sure how can i deploy the SFRA code using "OSF Builder Suite For Salesforce Commerce Cloud Deploy" plugin.

Found a way using Execute Shell option. Where i can write the whole script for each cartridge. But getting following error i.e:Error: no auth mechanism defined.

Is there any efficient way to upload the code through Jenkins? Please le